# Detecting center of image from parabolic mirror?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a panoramic one shot lens from here: http://www.0-360.com/ and I wrote a script using the python image library to "unwrap" the image into a panorama. I want to automate this process though, as currently I have to specify the center of the image. Also, getting the radius of the circle would be good too. The input image looks like this: [image]

And the "unwrapped" image looks like this: [image]

So far I have been trying the Hough Circle detection. The issues I have is selecting the correct values to use. Also, sometimes, dark objects near the center circle seem to throw it off.

Other Ideas I had:

1. Hough Line detection of the unwrapped image. Basically, choose center pixel as center, then unwrap and see if the lines on the top and bottom are straight or "curvy". If not straight, then keep trying with different centers.
2. Moments/blob detection. Maybe I can find the center blob and find the center of that. The problem is sometimes I get a bright ring in the center of the dark disk as seen in the image above. Also, the issue with dark objects near the center.
3. Paint the top bevel of the mirror a distinct color like green to make circle detection easier? If I use green and only use the green channel, would the detection be easier?

Whats the best method I should try and use to get the center of this image and possibly the radius of the outer and inner rings.

Answer (score 1):

As your image have multiple circle with common centre you can move that way, like

1. Detect circle with Hough circle and consider circle with  common centre.
2. Now check the ratio for co-centred circle, as your image keep that ratio constant.

Answer (score 1):

I guess don't make it too fancy. The black center is at the center of the image, right? Cut a square ROI close to the image center and look for 'black' region there. Store all the 'black' pixel locations and find their center. You may consider using CMYK color space for detecting the black region.